# filling an array to insert values of this array in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

1. The following is the get(); query :

```
$zero_others = DB::table('postusrs') 
                       ->where('post_id', $p_id)
                       ->where('user_id','!=', $op_id)
                       ->where('highted','=', 1)                   
                       ->get();
```

2. Here I will fill the array (which I believe is wrong, and I need to know the correct syntax)

```
$zero_id = $zero_others->id;
```

3. And lastly, I will update the group of IDs received in $zero_id into the DB :

```
 DB::table('postusrs')->where('id', $zero_id)->update(['highted' => 0]);
```

I'm seeing an error of: Trying to get property of non-object. Please advise how to fill the array ?

Comment: try to use first() instead of get()

Comment: I think first will return only 1 value, while I need all values.

Comment: can you var_dump the value of $zero_others , maybe there is no record that meets your conditions and it's returning null

Comment: Please specify Laravel version, I suppose you are not on the last one.

Comment: Laravel version 5.2.36

Comment: Changed my answer for the 5.2 laravel version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to collect an array of ids, in Laravel 5.2. Try this:

```
$zero_ids = DB::table('postusrs') 
                   ->where('post_id', $p_id)
                   ->where('user_id','!=', $op_id)
                   ->where('highted','=', 1)                   
                   ->pluck('id');
```

But you have to change the update query using `whereIn`:

```
DB::table('postusrs')->whereIn('id', $zero_ids)->update(['highted' => 0]);
```

Comment: I received this error : Call to a member function pluck() on array

Comment: I'm trying to update a group of IDs into the DB , Maybe I'm mistaken about the array. If it should be a collection, what will be the syntax ?

Comment: Still seeing the ((Call to a member function pluck() on array)) error

Comment: can you var_dump the value of $zero_others please ?

Comment: [zero_others] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 1 [created_at] => 2019-07-25 18:58:59 [updated_at] => 2019-07-25 18:58:59 [post_id] => 1 [user_id] => 1 [follow] => 0 [part_request] => 0 [part_me] => 0 [accepted] => 1 [highted] => 1 [draft] => ) ) )

Comment: you can't access $zero_others because it's returning a collection so you have to loop threw it using foreach to access the records returned by the query

Comment: I'm receiving this : Call to a member function all() on array.

Comment: For the following example, I'm not looping and the values are stored successfuly :

Comment: $acc_usrs = DB::table('postusrs')
                       ->join('users', 'postusrs.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
                       ->where('post_id', $id)
                       ->where('accepted', 1)
                       ->where('users.id','!=', $u_id)
                       ->get();

Comment: return view('finaltab', [ 'acc' => $acc_usrs]);

Comment: Laravel version 5.2.36

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.